# Ionic capacitor Motion plugin - listeners not triggering

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, motion

I have an ionic capacitor android app and I would like to record orientation and acceleration of the device, but after adding event listeners, they are not triggering.

Code:

```
import { Motion } from '@capacitor/motion';

export default class MotionService {

async startRecording() {
    try {
        await DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
    Motion.addListener('accel', event => {
        console.log('Device motion event:', event);
    });
}}
```

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.1.1",
    "@capacitor/app": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.1.1",
    "@capacitor/filesystem": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/motion": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "@ionic/vue": "^5.4.0",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^5.4.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0-0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
```

I am trying to test it by running: "ionic capacitor run android -l --host=MY_IP", emulator device is Pixel 3 API 30, then open chrome://inspect/#devices -> inspect to see console.logs and trying to change values in the option window of emulator: [image]

But I don't see any logs.
I would appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 0):

Silly question but ... Do you call `startRecording` function?

I checked this feature and It works fine on the `@ionic/angular` project. I don't think that there is some difference for `@ionic/vue`.

Moreover, I checked the [documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/motion#permissions) for `@capacitor/motion`. There are some points which need to keep in mind:

> This plugin is currently implemented using Web APIs. Most browsers
> require permission before using this API. To request permission,
> prompt the user for permission on any user-initiated action (such as a
> button click):

As I understand this plugin not using the native part. And seems `requestPermission` call is not needed (at least for Android).

Next point. [DeviceMotionEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceMotionEvent) is an experimental feature in the browser. So, It can be changing in some way in the future.

Anyway, you can also try cordova plugins if problems continue: [Device Motion](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device-motion) and [Device Orientation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device-orientation)

Answer (score 0):

Actually on Android you don't need to request permissions, just add listeners works

```
import { Motion } from '@capacitor/motion';
export default class MotionService {

async startRecording() {
    Motion.addListener('accel', event => {
        console.log('Device motion event:', event);
    });
}}
```

Comment: Tried the same but not working